# Top is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I write a code for a menu to scroll my page between different section (`id`)

Unfortunately I have a console error : cannot read property 'top' is undefined

```
  function goTo(ancre, diff, speed, ease){
            var diff = diff==undefined ? 86:diff;
            var speed = speed==undefined ? 1500:speed;
            var ease = ease==undefined ? 'easeInOutExpo':ease;
            var _tween = jQuery(ancre).offset().top-diff;

            jQuery('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop:_tween
            }, speed, ease);
    }
```

Can I have some help please ?

Comment: Make sure that the `ancre` you passed in parameters is exist.

Comment: And if it exists, is it an object. For example `ancre` should be `#idOfElement`, `.classOfSelector`, or `validElementName`